# Installing pip on Zorin

Tags: python, linux, pip

I am trying to install pip on Zorin 8. However when I use `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`, I get the following errors

```
Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.pair.com/archive/ saucy/main libexpat1-dev amd64 2.1.0-4
  404  Not Found

Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.pair.com/archive/ saucy/main libpython3-dev amd64 3.3.2-14ubuntu1
  404  Not Found

Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.pair.com/archive/ saucy/main python3-dev amd64 3.3.2-14ubuntu1
  404  Not Found

Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.pair.com/archive/ saucy/main python3-setuptools all 0.6.37-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found

Err http://ubuntu.mirrors.pair.com/archive/ saucy/universe python3-pip all 1.4.1-2
  404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.pair.com/archive/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1-dev_2.1.0-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.pair.com/archive/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/libpython3-dev_3.3.2-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.pair.com/archive/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-dev_3.3.2-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.pair.com/archive/pool/main/d/distribute/python3-setuptools_0.6.37-1ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirrors.pair.com/archive/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python3-pip_1.4.1-2_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Please suggest a solution. I have tried doing `sudo apt-get upgrade` before trying to install pip. The python 3.3.2+ version is installed on my workstation.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Python, then probably it already came with `pip` and it's a matter of adding pip's folder into `%path%` (or whatever environment variable Zorin uses for path indexing).

However, if you are *really* sure that you don't have `pip`, but you have Python, then you should look [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/), it contains all the binary data that installs `pip`.

Also, *are you even sure you have Python?* In case you don't have it, it might be useful to see if you can get a Zorin download at [Python's official website](http://python.org/). Also, as far as I researched, I found that Zorin runs Debian's [.deb packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)), which means that you might look for a Python .deb package.

**EDIT:** Maybe I should have said this in a comment, but heh, wouldn't fit, and this already helps C:

Comment: I used the `get-pip.py` file and installed pip using sudo. While installing the packages numpy and pandas I had to use `sudo pip2 install numpy`, i.e. instead of pip, I had to use pip2. Doing this shows that the requirement is already met, i.e. numpy is installed. However, when I try to run my code, it says "No module named numpy"

Comment: Do you happen to have both Python 2 and 3 installed? Check if there is a numpy-related folder in `[python folder]/lib`.

Comment: I have both python3 and python2 on my system. I could install numpy only for python2. I ran my code using python 2 and it runs fine. Thanks. I am facing this same problem while installing other packages. I guess my system is unable to locate packages. Do you think that this is due to incorrect system installation?

Comment: It seems that you will need to specify the full `pip` path to either Python 2 or Python 3. Or append it to `%path%` or whichever is your OS' folder-indexing environment variable.